# PHP - shuffle only part of an array

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I have an array as so:

```
$animals = array (
    'giraffe',
    'lion',
    'hippo',
    'dog',
    'cat',
    'rabbit',
    'fly',
    'hamster',
    'gerbil'
    'goldfish'
);
```

That is the order i want the array to be in apart from these 2 - `hamster` and `gerbil`

I would like to randomise between which one comes first. I know i can use:

```
shuffle($animals);
```

To randomise them all but i want to do it for just these 2. So if i was to do a `print_r($animals)` i may get hamster come before gerbil but another time get gerbil before hamster

Comment: note their position, remove them, shuffle, put them back in

Comment: Should those two values be randomized in the entire array, or just in terms of their own positions?

Comment: So do you want to swap `hamster` and `gerbil` 50% of the time, or do you want to randomize their position in the array?

Comment: I want to randomise their positions instead of a straight 50/50 split, and i want to randomise them in terms of their own position rather than in the entire array

Comment: @odd_duck: So in this case, you'd like to shuffle the 7th and 8th indices of the array?

Answer (score 10):

You can `splice` the array for those to elements, randomize their order and put them back in the original array:

```
$sub = array_splice($animals, 7, 2);
shuffle($sub);
array_splice($animals, 7, 0, $sub);
var_dump($animals);
```

Comment: @BenM this is an answer giving the idea on how solve the question. It's still a valid answer even though it didn't involved the actual code part since the asker has the proper knowledge on how to implement the solution.

Comment: @BenM I have to agree with Alex... This IS an answer for the user's issue ;)

Comment: I completely agree with Alex here, just because it doesn't give out a copy/paste solution, doesn't make it any less of an answer. I actually prefer that, as it still requires for the user to do some work.

Comment: OK, I don't understand where my original comment went, but when I commented, there was literally nothing more here than the opening sentence. Anyway, this now is a valid answer :)

Comment: +1, any idea on the efficiency of this over other approaches? eg shuffle only (needed) indexes and then just permute/re-arrange the original array?

Comment: @NikosM. It shuffles only the two items and then put them back in the original array. So i'd say it's pretty efficient unless you want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AlexLinte, correct, but splicing an array, can be an expensive operation, i have given an [alternative answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28491007/3591273) which does not require splice, it is a variation on fisher-yates-knuth shuffle (simnilar to php's shuffle function)

Answer (score 1):

Adding 2 variations of [Fisher-Yates-Knuth unbiased shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), with only included indices or excluded indices (php-like pseudo-code)

```
function shuffle_include( $a, $inc ) 
{
    // $a is array to shuffle
    // $inc is array of indices to be included only in the shuffle
    // all other elements/indices will remain unaltered

    // fisher-yates-knuth shuffle variation O(n)
    $N = count($inc);
    while ( $N-- )
    { 
        $perm = rnd( 0, $N ); 
        $swap = $a[ $inc[$N] ]; 
        $a[ $inc[$N] ] = a[ $inc[$perm] ]; 
        $a[ $inc[$perm] ] = $swap; 
    }
    // in-place
    return $a;
}

function shuffle_exclude( $a, $exc ) 
{
    // $a is array to shuffle
    // $exc is array of indices to be excluded from the shuffle
    // all other elements/indices will be shuffled
    // assumed excluded indices are given in ascending order
    $inc = array();
    $i=0; $j=0; $l = count($a); $le = count($exc)
    while ($i < $l)
    {
        if ($j >= $le || $i<$exc[$j]) $inc[] = $i;
        else $j++;
        $i++;
    }
    // rest is same as shuffle_include function above

    // fisher-yates-knuth shuffle variation O(n)
    $N = count($inc);
    while ( $N-- )
    { 
        $perm = rnd( 0, $N ); 
        $swap = $a[ $inc[$N] ]; 
        $a[ $inc[$N] ] = $a[ $inc[$perm] ]; 
        $a[ $inc[$perm] ] = $swap; 
    }
    // in-place
    return $a;
}
```

Example:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

print_r( shuffle_include( $a, array(0,1,2) ) );
// sample output: [2,1,3,4,5,6] , only 0,1,2 indices are shuffled

print_r( shuffle_exclude( $a, array(0,1,2) ) );
// sample output: [1,2,3,6,5,4], all other indices are shuffled except 0,1,2
```

**NOTE** That PHP's shuffle function itself uses a variation of Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffling algorithm

**NOTE2** All shuffle algorithms given (and PHP's original shuffle function) have a (average) time complexity of $O(n)$ (n=size of array to shuffle)

for other variations of `shuffle` see:

1. [Efficiently pick n random elements from PHP array (without shuffle)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035986/3591273)

Answer (score 0):

```
$animals = array (
'giraffe',
'lion',
'hippo',
'dog',
'cat',
'rabbit',
'fly',
'goldfish'
);
$other = array('hamster','gerbil');
$allAnimals = array();
foreach($animals as $key => $animal){
    if($key == 7){
        $allAnimals = array_merge($allAnimals,shuffle($other));
    }
$allAnimals[] = $animal;
}
```

Comment: What if the index is *not* always the 7th?

Answer (score 0):

```
function shuffle_include($a, $include_indexes)    
{    
    $b = array();    
    foreach ($include_indexes as $i => $v)    
        $b[] = $a[$v];    
            
    shuffle($b);    
    
    foreach ($include_indexes as $i => $v)    
        $a[$v] = $b[$i];    
     
    return $a;    
}
```

Example:

```
$animals = array (
'giraffe',
'lion',
'hippo',
'dog',
'cat',
'rabbit',
'fly',
'hamster',
'gerbil',
'goldfish');

$new_animals = shuffle_include($animals, array(7,8));
```