# Algorithm to return all combinations of k out of n as well as corresponding complement list

Tags: algorithm

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n), but I also want the corresponding complement ordered list that contains the element not chosen **in an efficient way** using python or c++. For example, with an ordered list `list=(0,1,1,2,3,3)` when we choose 3 elements, one possible return pair should be `(0,1,3)` and `(1,2,3)`. Additionally, I want the function to return a total of  C(n,k) terms, so that the pair `(0,1,3)` and `(1,2,3)` should repeat 4 times in the returned result.

Full example of a short input: define a function `foo(list,k)`, then `foo([0,1,1],1)` should return a list `r` of length C(3,1)=3,

```
r(0)=[[0],[1,1]] (choose 0, complement list is [1,1])
r(1)=[[1],[0,1]] (choose first 1, complement list is [0,1])
r(2)=[[1],[0,1]] (choose second 1, complement list is [0,1])
```

Comment: i'm not sure i understand, maybe add some examples or explanation. For example what exactly is the "*complement ordered list*"? What exactly does this mean "when we choose 3 elements, one possible return pair should be (0,1,3) and (1,2,3)"?

Comment: I added an example according to your suggestions. The complement list is a list containing the element not chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a basic combinations-algorithm, with the exception that it returns a tuple: the elements that are "in" and those that are "out". Then just recursively generate combinations for the rest of the list and add the first element to either the "in" or the "out" list, respectively.

Here's some Python code:

```py
def comb_and_comp(lst, n):
    # no combinations
    if len(lst) < n:
        return
    # trivial 'empty' combination
    if n == 0 or lst == []:
        yield [], lst
    else:
        first, rest = lst[0], lst[1:]
        # combinations that contain the first element
        for in_, out in comb_and_comp(rest, n - 1):
            yield [first] + in_, out
        # combinations that do not contain the first element
        for in_, out in comb_and_comp(rest, n):
            yield in_, [first] + out
```

This will create both the "in" and "out" lists in one go, instead of creating the complement in a second pass.

Comment: It's a more efficient one and  I think it can scale nicely for really big lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok then use the [algorithm here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) to generate all combinations of k over n and then use this algorithm to get the complementary list

(assume that the combination is given in indices and not actual values)
for your example this would be:

```
foo([0,1,1],1) // i.e indices are [0,1,2] with values [0,1,1]
r(0)=[[0],[1,2]] (choose 0, complement list is [1,2])
r(1)=[[1],[0,2]] (choose first 1, complement list is [0,2])
r(2)=[[1],[0,1]] (choose second 1, complement list is [0,1])
```

The algorithm is (adapted [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28491007/3591273)):

```
def complement(n, k, combination):
    # assume the combination values/indices are given in ascending order (i.e lexicographic)
    complement = []
    i=0 
    j=0 
    while i < n:
        if j >= k or i<combination[j]: complement.append(i)
        else: j+=1
        i+=1
    return complement
```

Comment: Which algorithm/implementation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n do you mean exactly?

Comment: @moi, oops sorry I misread your comment and referring to another answer. Actually it doesn matter which algorithm one will choose as long as it generates combinations of k over n. Choose one that suits you, although being able to generate the indexes instead of only ther values is a requirement