# PHP shuffle with seed?

Tags: php

How can I make the php shuffle function use a seed, so that when I use the same seed, the shuffle function will output the same array. I read that shuffle is automatically seeded. Is there a way to get the seed of that shuffle used, or how can I create/mimic shuffle with a custom seed?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: You can't pass a seed to `shuffle()`. `shuffle()` is there to shuffle an array.

Answer (score 5):

You can't retrieve the seed used by shuffle, but you can simulate shuffle and fix your own seed:

```
$array = range(1, 10);

function seededShuffle(array &$array, $seed) {
    mt_srand($seed);
    $size = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i) {
        list($chunk) = array_splice($array, mt_rand(0, $size-1), 1);
        array_push($array, $chunk);
    }
}

$seed = date('Ymd');
seededShuffle($array, $seed);
var_dump($array);
```

This will set a different seed each day, but throughout the day it will use the same seed and shuffle the array in the same order; tomorrow will be a different random shuffle to today

For today (6th June 2015), the sequence should be

```
3, 6, 9, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5, 10, 4
```

Comment: i would recommend to use the [fisher-yates-knuth shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to generate the shuffling with given seed, as it is `O(n)` , **unbiased** and does **not need** `array_splice`s which can be expensive (operates in-place)

Answer (score -1):

PHP does not have shuffling with seeding, but you can do this instead:

```
$an_array = array('a','b','c','d');
$indices = array(0,1,2,3);

// shuffle the indices and use them as shuffling seed
shuffle($indices);

// then whenever you want to produce exactly same shuffle use the pre-computed shuffled indices
function shuffle_precomputed($a, $shuffled_indices)
{
     $b = $a; // copy array
     foreach ($shuffled_indices as $i1=>$i2) $a[$i2] = $b[$i1];
     return $a;
}
```

use like this:

```
$shuffled_array = shuffle_precomputed($an_array, $indices);
```

You can even use the [factoradic number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) to transform the `$shuffled_indices` array to/from a unique integer number that can be used as a unique seed, then simply compute the shuffle from the factoradic number to be used in `shuffle_precomputed` function.

For additional `shuffle` variations for PHP you may want to see:

1. [PHP - shuffle only part of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718843/php-shuffle-only-part-of-an-array/28491007#28491007)
2. [Efficiently pick n random elements from PHP array (without shuffle)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035986/3591273)

Comment: This does not solve the problem as as the 'indices' are not a seed, as requested by the OP.

Comment: In your solution the actual shuffling is happening at `shuffle($indices)` - wihtout a given seed. Saving the solution doesn't solve the problem either. Your solution doesn't solve the problem.