# Weighted random numbers in 2D Array - Processing

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, processing, random

I would like to fill a 3x3 2D array with values 1,2,3.

I need each number to appear for a given times.

**For example:**

```
1 to appear 2 times
2 to appear 4 times
3 to appear 3 times
```

What I need is to store this numbers to array in a random position.

**For Example:**

```
  1,2,2
  3,2,2
  1,3,3
```

I already did this in a simple way using only 2 different numbers controlled by a counter. So I loop through the 2D array and applying random values of number 1 and number 2. 
I'm checking if the value is 1 and add it in the counter and the same with number 2. if one of the counter exceeds the number I have set as the maximum appear times then it continues and applies the other value.

Is there any better approach to fill the 3 numbers in random array position?

See code below:

```
int [][] array = new int [3][3];

int counter1 =0;
int counter2 =0;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        array[i][j] = (int)random(1, 3); //1,2 

          if (arrray[i][j]==1) {
          counter1++;
        } else if (array[i][j] ==2) {
          counter2++;
        } 
       //if it is more than 5 times in the array put only the other value
        if (counter1>5) {
          array[i][j] = 2;
        } 
        //if it is more than 4 times in the array put only the other value
        else if (counter2>4) {
          array[i][j] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
```

---

I finally did this according to this discussion:

[How can I generate a random number within a range but exclude some?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443176/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-within-a-range-but-exclude-some), with 1D array for tesing, but it does not always works. 
Please see attached code:

```
int []values = new int[28];
int counter1=0;
int counter2=0;
int counter3=0;

for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
      if (counter1==14) {
        ex = append(ex, 5);
      }  
      if (counter2==4) {
        ex =append(ex, 6);
      }  
      if (counter3==10) {
        ex =append(ex, 7);
      }
      values[i] = getRandomWithExclusion(5, 8, ex);

      if (values[i]==5) {
        counter1++;
      } else if (values[i] ==6) {
        counter2++;
      } else if (values[i] ==7) {
        counter3++;
      }
    }

int getRandomWithExclusion(int start, int end, int []exclude) {
    int rand = 0;
    do {
      rand = (int) random(start, end);
    } 
    while (Arrays.binarySearch (exclude, rand) >= 0);
    return rand;
  }
```

I would like to fill the 1D array with values of 5,6 or 7. Each one a specific number. Number 5 can be added 14 times. Number 6 can be added 4 times. Number 7 can be added 10 times.

The above code works most of the times, however somethimes it does not. Please let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: If you have another question, please post it as its own second question instead of editing this question.

Comment: Is the same question. I just added what I have done. However this algorithm doesn't work always as expected. @KevinWorkman

Comment: Your original question was how to fill a 2D array with particular numbers. You were given several answers that do exactly that. Why don't you use one of those solutions? If you're asking why a specific solution doesn't work, that's a separate question. It's up to you how to proceed, but you won't get many answers if you just keep adding questions to this already answered question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Octave/Matlab code for your problem.

```
n=3;
N=n*n;
count = [1 2; 2 4; 3 3];
if sum(count(:,2)) ~= N
    error('invalid input');
end
m = zeros(n, n);
for i = 1:size(count,1)
    for j = 1:count(i,2)
        r = randi(N);
        while m(r) ~= 0
            r = randi(N);
        end
        m(r) = count(i,1);
    end
end
disp(m);
```

Please note that when you address a 2D array using only one index, Matlab/Octave would use [Column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

Comment: This question is about [tag:processing], not matlab.

Comment: I think you are mistaken Kevin, as the asker has used the label java! so processing here is meant to be interpretted literally, not as the Processing language.

Comment: Please research what Processing is. It's a language/library based on Java. View the [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:495296+[processing]) that the user has posted about Processing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of ways to do this. Since you're using [processing](/questions/tagged/processing), one way is to create an `IntList` from all of the numbers you want to add to your array, shuffle it, and then add them to your array. Something like this:

```
IntList list = new IntList();
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){ //add numbers 1 through 3
   for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){ add each 3 times
      list.append(i);
   }
}

list.shuffle();

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
      array[i][j] = list.remove(0);
   }
}
```

You could also go the other way: create an ArrayList of locations in your array, shuffle them, and then add your ints to those locations.

Comment: I am unable to find IntList class.

Comment: @Dante This is a question about the Processing language. IntList is a standard class: https://www.processing.org/reference/IntList.html

Comment: Ok i get it.What do you think of my solution?