# How to randomly generate a float between two values with a variable number of ranges excluded?

Tags: c#, random

For example, if I wanted to generate a random float between 0 - 100, but exclude the values 1.097 - 3. 346, 7.0001 - 8.9996, 14.5 - 38.6, 50 - 50.389, 75.648 - 88.8975, etc? I thought this would be a simple problem, but there doesn't even seem to be Range object in c#, and there is no RandWithExclusion() method.

I have seen all these questions,
[How can I generate a random number within a range but exclude some?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443176/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-within-a-range-but-exclude-some)
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124059/how-can-i-exclude-a-range-of-values-when-generating-random-numbers
[How to get a random number from a range, excluding some values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484577/how-to-get-a-random-number-from-a-range-excluding-some-values)
none of them are even remotely useful. Is what I'm doing really such a rare problem?

How would I even go about doing this? (Without brute-forcing, please.)

Comment: How are those questions not useful? The first one seems incredibly transferrable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a random number within a range but exclude some?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443176/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-within-a-range-but-exclude-some)

Comment: I would take the first solution, convert it to C# and extend it to support _multiple_ exclusion ranges.

Comment: The linked questions all deal with exclusions for integer ranges. Solving the same problem for floating-point ranges requires more finesse, especially for multiple ones, especially if you don't want to mess up the distribution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's *slightly* more work, but not much.  It's pretty similar.  But yes, it's not the same.

Comment: @Servy: care to take a shot at writing up an answer then? :-) This does not seem to be a duplicate.

Comment: @JeroenMostert all linked questions suggest "generate value, repeat if excluded". I don't think it will "mess up the distribution" (not an expert so, please clarify why you believe it is more complicated than that).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Repeating generation will indeed not mess up the distribution, but the OP specified "without brute forcing", which I assume excludes this approach. (Whether that's a wise thing to do is another matter, I'd have no qualms with it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a little pre-processing before drawing the numbers to get a list of possible ranges. So let's assume we have a Range structure like so:

```
/// <summary> A possible range of values. </summary>
public struct Range
{
    /// <summary> Min value, inclusive. </summary>
    public readonly double Min;
    /// <summary> Max value, inclusive. </summary>
    public readonly double Max;
    public Range(double min, double max) { Min = min; Max = max; }
    /// <summary> Range length, distance between Min and Max. </summary>
    public double Length { get { return Max - Min; } }
}
```

And another structure RangeList which holds several ranges together. Range list also contains a cumulative length array of successive length sums of your Ranges, like so:

```
/// <summary> All possible ranges grouped together. </summary>
public struct RangeList
{
    /// <summary> Possible range. </summary>
    public readonly Range[] Ranges;
    /// <summary> Sum of each range length. </summary>
    public readonly double Length;
    /// <summary> Cumulative lengths values of each ranges. </summary>
    public readonly double[] CumulLengths;
    public RangeList(Range[] ranges)
    {
        Ranges = ranges;
        Length = 0;
        CumulLengths = new double[ranges.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < ranges.Length; ++i)
        {
            Length += ranges[i].Length;
            CumulLengths[i] = Length;
        }
    }
}
```

We can then write easily a function that creates a RangeList from a given list of excluded ranges:

```
    /// <summary> Get possible ranges to draw from, considering exclusions. </summary>
    public static RangeList GetRangeList(Range range, params Range[] exclusions)
    {
        var ranges = new List<Range>();
        ranges.Add(range);
        if (exclusions != null)
        {
            foreach (var exclusion in exclusions)
            { // progressively eat latest range added to the list, cutting exclusions.
                var lastRange = ranges[ranges.Count - 1];
                if (exclusion.Min < lastRange.Max)
                {
                    ranges[ranges.Count - 1] = new Range(lastRange.Min, exclusion.Min);
                    if (exclusion.Max < lastRange.Max)
                    {
                        ranges.Add(new Range(exclusion.Max, lastRange.Max));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new RangeList(ranges.ToArray());
    }
```

This method relies on several assumptions, including that not all space is excluded, exclusions are not overlapping, and exclusions are given in ascending order.
It is then straight-forward to draw a number from the possible ranges:

```
    /// <summary> Assume exclusions are also given in ranges. </summary>
    public static double RangeWithExclusions(this Random random, Range range, params Range[] exclusions)
    {
        var rangeList = GetRangeList(range, exclusions);
        var rnd = random.NextDouble() * rangeList.Length;
        var rangeIndex = Array.BinarySearch(rangeList.CumulLengths, rnd);
        if (rangeIndex < 0)
        { // 'unlucky', we didn't hit a length exactly
            rangeIndex = ~rangeIndex;
        }
        var previousLength = rangeIndex > 0 ? rangeList.CumulLengths[rangeIndex - 1] : 0;
        var rndRange = rangeList.Ranges[rangeIndex]; // result range of our random draw
        return rndRange.Min + (rnd - previousLength); // scale rnd back into range space
    }
```

The following NUnit test demonstrate how to use the solution:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestRandom
{
    [Test]
    public void Tests()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        double rnd;
        rnd = random.RangeWithExclusions(new Range(0, 1));
        Assert.IsTrue(rnd >= 0 && rnd <= 1);
        rnd = random.RangeWithExclusions(new Range(-100, 1));
        Assert.IsTrue(rnd >= -100 && rnd <= 1);
        rnd = random.RangeWithExclusions(new Range(0, 1), new Range(0.1, 0.9));
        Assert.IsTrue(rnd >= 0 && rnd <= 1 && (rnd <= 0.1 || rnd >= 0.9));
        rnd = random.RangeWithExclusions(new Range(0, 1), new Range(0, 0.9));
        Assert.IsTrue(rnd >= 0 && rnd <= 1 && (rnd >= 0.9));
        rnd = random.RangeWithExclusions(new Range(0, 1), new Range(0.2, 0.4), new Range(0.6, 0.8));
        Assert.IsTrue(rnd >= 0 && rnd <= 1 && (rnd <= 0.2 || rnd >= 0.4) && (rnd <= 0.6 || rnd >= 0.8));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

1. Consider the ranges you do want to include R1, R2, ... Assume they are non-overlapping and in order.
2. Add up their total spans (end-start). You now have a contiguous range for your random number (zero to sum(spans)).
3. Generate a number in that range.
4. Now map that number back onto the non-contiguous ranges:

   1. If it's less than first range's span, add it to start of first range and return it.
   2. Otherwise, subtract first range's span from it, compare to second span etc.

[image]

Comment: Note that for somewhat large number of ranges to check binary search would be better option - O(log n_ranges)) vs. suggested linear search O(n_ranges).

Comment: Incredibly useful, thanks, just one thing: "add it to **start** of first range and return it" — did you perhaps mean **end?** I ask because I tested both, and adding the start of the first range resulted in significantly more excluded numbers being outputted. (Though I should mention that both ways resulted in excluded numbers being outputted).

Comment: Nope, add the random offset to the start of the range, see diagram I added.

Comment: This does not solve OPs question. OP wanted to EXCLUDE ranges not INCLUDE ranges. Your algorithm is for including certain ranges.

Comment: @StephenPorter The transformation from 'excludes' to 'includes' is utterly trivial for non-overlapping, in-order intervals. I omitted it because the diagram shows it and it's not the real crux of how to solve this even-random-distribution problem. I can add a step 0 to do that if Op asks for it although I consider step 1 to already imply it.

Answer (score -2):

This is pretty simple... probably a good one that you should have sat and figured out on your own for learning purposes (especially since you yourself say that it's a simple problem).

This isn't the best way nor the most efficient way to do this by any means, but it's a naive approach that works with little thinking required. The drawbacks are that if you run this multiple times (e.g. a million times) you'll generate quite a bit of duplicates.

```
public class Range
{
    public float MinValue { get; set; }
    public float MaxValue { get; set; }
}

public static class FloatGenerator
{
    public static float GenerateFloatWithExclusionsInANaiveWay(int minValue, int maxValue, params Range[] rangeExclusions)
    {
        // We don't care about ranges outside of the min and max values allowed
        var allowedRanges = rangeExclusions.Where(r => r.MinValue >= minValue && r.MaxValue <= maxValue);

        // We use a guid to generate a random seed that random will use (reduces chance of duplicates)
        var random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        // We will use this to keep a pool of random values that fit within our expected ranges
        var randomPool = new List<float>();

        // Loop through each of the ranges and get a value that fits the range
        foreach (var range in allowedRanges)
        {
            var randomValue = float.MaxValue;
            while (randomValue < range.MinValue || randomValue > range.MaxValue)
            {
                randomValue = (random.Next((int)range.MinValue, (int)range.MaxValue) + (float)random.NextDouble());
            }

            randomPool.Add(randomValue);
        }

        // Return one of the acceptable random numbers randomly
        return randomPool.ElementAt(random.Next(0, randomPool.Count - 1));
    }
}
```

If you want to get fancier, you can look at the other answers that put more thought into it than you probably wanted.

Comment: "a good one that you should have sat and figured out on your own for learning purposes" which means you shouldn't do his hw for him

Comment: This does not in fact exclude ranges, it only excludes specific values.  This code is also highly likely to result in a stack overflow exception.

Comment: @Steve Yea, you're right, but OP obviously spent more time googling for an answer and writing a post to ask for it than thinking about it. I tend to find people that do this will spend ten times the amount of time going to every coding forum and posting the same question over and over until someone answers it for them. Might as well stop the forum spamming here.